# Android Thread in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I had some code in a shouldOverrideUrlLoading, that downloads the data, converting if necessary, and shows in a WebView using loadData or loadUrl. I moved this to a thread (a class implementing Runnable), and now it doesn't lock up the UI while the next page is loading. Unfortunately, sometimes it locks up the whole app, and pausing while debugging shows it seems to be going nowhere (deadlock?)

I'm guessing this is because UI isn't thread-safe, not even webkit loadData/loadUrl? Is there a way to set some sort of onFinish action that runs in UI thread after download/convert has finished? Or would it be enough to store the current thread, and cancel it before running another thread??

Comment: You should consider using `AsyncTask` instead of a `Thread`

Comment: I thought of that, but I just found this:http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html After putting the UI commands in view.post(new Runnable(, it seems to not freeze anymore. I thought about AsyncTask but I wanted way to do this in normal Java.

Comment: It's better to stick to Android practices, not to "normal java". Will save a lot of time in the future.. :)

Comment: I've used AsyncTask, it works fine but sometimes it seemed to call the onPostExecute instead of onCancelled. I was also wondering how this could be done without the Android additions like webview.post and AsyncTask, e.g. on a desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a synchronized (WebView) { around the thread's code fixes this.